# Android Studio - Erro ao utilizar os métodos do BottomNavigationViewEx

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Boa tarde, estou utilizando a lib *BottomNavigationViewEx* para fazer uma barra de navegação para uma aplicação Android, mas quando vou utilizar os métodos `"enableXXXX"` e o `"setTextVisibility"` dá o erro abaixo. Alguém sabe porquê e como resolver? Obrigado.
PS: o `"setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener"` funciona.

**Erro:**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.getBottomNavigationItemViews(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:569) at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:341) at io.github.bfaguiar.ianthe.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:64) `
```

**Código:**

```
BottomNavigationViewEx bnav = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bnve);
bnav.enableAnimation(false);
bnav.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
bnav.enableShiftingMode(false);
bnav.setTextVisibility(false);
bnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

Comment: Segundo  [https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/issues/52](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/issues/52), pode ser a versão da support library.

Comment: Obrigado, não experimentei mudar a versão, mas na nova versão, o bottom navbar deles já deixa alterar o que precisava através do xml. Voltei à navbar original (BottomNavigationView apenas).